# Display collapsible content within a Div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've searched around the web for a solution to my problem and im getting pretty close to my desired design with Accordion JQuery but..
I have some extension to the JQuery template which I dont know how to implement, so here it goes:

This is how my Div looks when you enter the webpage:
[image]

When you hover over either the picture or the title/text the text will be underlined and italic so that the user know the feature with cliking on it.
What I would like see if the visitor clicks the picture/text is this:

[image]

This is my HTML for that specific Div

```
<a href="#">
<div class="newsbox">
    <img src="" class="fast" /><span class="newstitle">DarkShift Studios Web</span>
    <br />
    <p>We are pleased to present our first release of the Web-headquarter. Everything you see on these webpages have been builed from scratch, HTML/CSS and JS code, no CMS programs have been used. ...</p>
    <div class="vertical_accordion_toggle">
        <p></p>
    </div>
</div>
</a>
```

**Code:**
http://jsfiddle.net/VCDe2/1/

Appreciate any hints/tips!

Comment: Take a look at jQuery and `slideDown` https://api.jquery.com/slideDown/

Comment: It seems like its working in the same fashion as Accordion. The difference is that i want the exact same div to change in height when pressed on (more or less) not a new div to show

Comment: You can do this simply by nesting the other div in the parent.  I'll create an answer in a sec.

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/VCDe2/3/

Comment: @adaam2 Its pretty close, even though its bugging a bit :) 
- I would like to start the "new text" at the "..." mark 
-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/piedoom/zzMkj/) to show you what's happening.

jQuery:

```
$('h1').click(function(){ 
    $(this).next('.hidden').slideToggle();
});
```

Simple enough!  Adaam's fiddle in the post above certainly does work, but I'd recommend not using it as it will only work for one item - you'll need to add more code for every new section you create.

This solution, however, will look for any `h1` item when it is clicked, and then find the next `.hidden` class item closest to it, allowing you to add as many different areas as you want.

For instance, with the same code above, you can scale everything up to work like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/piedoom/zzMkj/1/) with no extra jQuery script.

All you have to do to incorperate it into your project is make sure your `.hidden` equivalent is nested inside of a container with the rest of the section, and change `h1` and `.hidden` to fit your proper classnames.  Make sure they're classnames, as IDs will not work.

Comment: This is good. I only got one question - is it possible to change "..." with a new line of text when we click ?

Comment: Actually, I think I need to go back an revise my answer.  Taking a look at how you have your DOM set up, using `.next` won't work, unfortunately.  If you only have 1 box set up, Adaam's answer will work fine.

Comment: I actually have 5-6 boxes that should have same functionality - im gonna mark this as answer (Y) thank you

Comment: To replace the dots.. use something like this: `$('#dots').replaceWith($('.vertical_accordion_toggle').slideToggle());`

Comment: Thats actually not a bad idea adaam - i'll look into it. Thank you